# Any way for me as developer to prevent that Phone Nightmode setting closes my App forcefully?

Tags: android, properties, runtime

Sorry that I can't be more specific with this topic.
I'm looking for possible clues of a problem and if there is a known solution for developers:
Many commonly used devices, like the Samsung Galaxy S8/S9/S10, have a Night mode setting/Dark theme setting.
I noticed that toggling this setting closes many game app processes forcefully for no reason, while other game runtimes are not affected by that setting.
Do I have any control about that as a developer?
Google Play apps by Nitrome, "Redungeon", "Tower Fortress" will close forcefully when toggling Night mode on or off, but all apps I tested that runs with Unity engine for example are not affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this happens because a switch to dark mode triggers a configuration change. A configuration change will lead to recreation of an activity unless you explicitly tell the OS, that you will handle the change yourself, as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#configuration_changes).

> When the app’s theme changes (either through the system setting or
>   AppCompat) it triggers a uiMode configuration change. This means that
>   Activities will be automatically recreated.

As a developer you'll need to add `android:configChanges="uiMode"` in your manifest to your game's activity to prevent a forced recreation when the OS changes the theme.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="uiMode" />
```

I am not a Unity developer but I assume unity ignores all configuration changes per default.